# Why do some applications use ~/.config/appname for their config data while others use ~/.appname?

Tags: configuration, home, posix, freedesktop, dot-files

I've noticed that some applications put their configuration files to `~/.config/appname` while others use `~/.appname` (the classic way, AFAIK) for this. What's the sense in this distinction and what could be better to consider for an application of mine?

UPDATE: Looks like my (XUbuntu 11.10 default) $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is set to `~/` and the most of the applications in my system (like Mozilla Firefox, Adobe Flash Player, Midnight Commander, Opera, Wine, etc.) comply to this. But there are still many applications (like Compiz, Deadbeef, VLC, Qt Creator, Google Chrome, XFCE, etc.) using `~/.config/` instead. Another suspicious thing is that directories in `~/.config/` are not themselves hidden (no dot in their names) - aren't application config dirs expected to have constant own names without depending on the location ($XDG_CONFIG_HOME value)?

Answer (score 56):

A complement to jasonwryan's great answer, addressing some of your issues:

- Your `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is ***not*** set to `~/`. It simply isn't set. So applications *that follow the XDG Specification* use the default `~/.config`
- The dirs inside `/.config` are not hidden because they don't have to. The whole point of using a `~/.config` dir is to ***un-clutter*** the user's `$HOME`. Since they are already in a separate, hidden dir, there's no need to be hidden inside there.
- Software that does not follow the spec (unfortunately still the vast majority) use a hidden dir for their settings (like `~/.myapp`) as an *attempt* not to clutter the user's `$HOME`. It (kinda) works, but it is still a bad approach when, for example, you try to backup your settings and your "big data" (like Pictures, Videos, Music) separately. Having all settings in a single place, without mixing with user's data, is a much better approach
- As for *"having constant names regardless of where `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` points to"* , they already do: it is `appname` *without* the leading dot. Remember: the ones using `$HOME/.appname` are the ones that *ignore* XDG Spec. They use a hardcoded path.
- As for your applications, ***please use the XDG Standard***! I beg you, and your users will thank you for not cluttering their home directory any further.

Comment: Just want to say your answer is **most** excellent! The conventional wisdom is particularly useful and your points are very well explained :) thanks!

Comment: Where is the difference between a list of hidden files in the HOME directory and a list of non hidden files in a hidden configuration directory? For me it is as broad as it is long.

Comment: @ceving: I see 2 main differences, a cosmetic and a practical one: from your `$HOME` point of view, it's a single `~/.config` entry instead of several, perhaps dozens of them. And it makes backups of your settings (or excluding them) much much easier! How can you tell apart software settings from, say, your `~/Documents` or your `~/.cache`?

Answer (score 31):

Because those applications that place configuration files in `$HOME` are ignoring the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/index.html#introduction), notably:

> There is a single base directory relative to which user-specific configuration files should be written. This directory is defined by the environment variable $XDG_CONFIG_HOME...
> If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is either not set or empty, a default equal to $HOME/.config should be used.

Comment: Looks like my (XUbuntu 11.10 default) `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is set to `~/`, but there are still many applications using `~/.config/`

Comment: This answer is far from complete. Namely, it seems to imply that the specification has been there since day one, and it's just the apps which have ignored it since the beginning. But actually there are quite some apps which have been around for much longer than XDG with its specification.

Comment: A version 0.7 Poettering standard. That must be really important. Can anybody explain which problem the standard solves?

Comment: @Ruslan: It's been there since 2003. That's **15 years** ago! True, that's not day one and many software was created before that. But any such software most likely had many updates to be still in use today, so it's safe to say the ones that didn't migrate to the XDG standard deliberately chose to ignore it.

Comment: @ceving: it solves the problem of organizing user's dirs the same way `/`is organized: not mixing data with executables with configuration. `~/.config` is the user's counterpart of `/etc`, and this helps tremendously in backups for example. Without `/.config`, any settings backup would have to either manually include all apps dirs or manually exclude all users "big data" dirs (Videos, Music, and any other personal dirs he might have created).

Comment: @MestreLion All dot files are configuration. If you want to backup your configuration, save all dot files and directories. The so called standard is useless.

Comment: @ceving: that's not true, dot files in user's HOME tree can also be  logs (`.xsession-errors`), state/lock files (`.gksu.lock`), cache files, and even device/block files. Many of them you _don't_ want to backup.

Comment: @ceving: But anyway, it's a standard intended to better organize things and improve interoperability - think about `~/.cache`, `~/.local/bin`, `~/.local/lib` (used by Python's `pip`) - but in the end you're free to ignore it if you want to.

Answer (score 9):

A more controversial answer is:

- `~/.config` is the default for the XDG standard, which only applies to applications adhering to the FreeDesktop.org standards (also via use of the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` variable).
- `~/.appname` existed before the freedesktop standard
- Not everyone likes the freedesktop standard
- "Cluttering" `$HOME` isn't a problem, in my opinion.

Comment: That's not a controversial answer, it's a misleading and plain wrong one:
- Currently I have 120 directories at `~/.config`, from applications that have no relation to FreeDesktop.org, such as Libre Office, Chromium, Deluge, a lot of games (including but not only **all** games using Unity3D), Google apps (Chrome, Earth), Python stuff (IPython, Eric), Emulators (Muppen 64, Desmune). FreeDesktop.org itself has very few applications.

- `~/.appname` is a convention that existed before XDG, but most software still in use today was created way *after* the standard.

Comment: - From a software developer's perspective, there's nothing to like or dislike in a directory standard, it simply changes your save dir constant from `$HOME/.myapp` to `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/myapp`

Comment: Is still a freedesktop standard, defined here : https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html and which applications are free not to use of they don't wish to.  Not everyone considers the separation into .config necessary.

Comment: True, but implying that applications that follow the standard are somehow "FreeDesktop.org applications" is very misleading.

Comment: Updated to say apps which use the freedesktop standards instead.

Comment: are there any benefits to `~/.app` over `~/.config/app`?

Comment: While some may think the clutter is not a problem, if your app clutters my `$HOME` and I have a choice, I'm not using your app - *looking at you, Snap*.