# configuration ethics (esthetics): /etc vs $HOME

Tags: configuration, directory-structure, home, etc

Ok this may not be a very concrete question, and is perhaps subject to taste, yet I'm struggling to get this right so here it goes.

I have a computer.
This computer has linux on it (thank god). Arch Linux to be specific (with `awesome` wm).
I am the single user on this computer.

As to good practice I've set up two users: the `root` user and the everyday use `romeovs` user. This way I only use permissions when needed (using `sudo` for example).

Over the years I have been pimping out my software suite, adding a bunch of applications to this computer. Notably: `vim`, `git`, `mpc`, `mutt`, `calcurse`, `ufw`, ...

Now here is the rub: which of these applications' config files do I use? All of these supply an `/etc`-based *global* configuration file, that affects *all* users, as well as a *local* `~/.config` (or, sadly, `~/`) config options.

I've always worked using the local configuration setups, because this felt more natural. But as I grow more familiar with my computer, I feel this somehow lacks elegance. The contra's to this approach are:

- dicrepancy when switching to `root` user, even with `sudo` (e.g. when using `vim`)
- will not always work, e.g. when loading deamons from the arch linux `DEAMONS`
  array they are run by the `root` user and thus don't pick up local user configs.
- major `$HOME` directory clutter. Sadly there are very few apps that adhere to the [`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24347/11279) philosophy.

Benefits are:

- stuff is local, which feels more in the lines of the permissions splitting between `root` and `romeovs`.
- quick and easy acces to the files. no need to `sudo` to edit them.
- easier for `git` tracking of the config files.
- somehow feels safer: a user can screw stuff up without messign with the machine's global settings.
- it is more "a-package-update-may-overwite-my-config"-proof

Let's get conrete:

> What is the de-facto standard to split configuration on a single user machine, especially for the system maintainer (single-user)?

Comment: Maybe [etckeeper](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/) can help you - it tracks config files in `/etc` using `git` (or `hg`, `darcs`, `bzr´).

Comment: I've tried that, but I prefer managing it mysefl with git. This is not the main problem though. It is about what is the 'right' thing to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One day you're going to change your computer, or to give someone else (a family member, for example) an account on your computer.

- If you want to keep a setting on your next computer, put it in your home directory.
- If the other person might want a different setting, put it in your home directory.
- If the setting is computer-dependent and not user-dependent, put it in `/etc`.

Your arguments against putting configuration files in the home directory don't really hold water:

- `sudo` keeps the `HOME` environment variable (unless you've told it not to). So your programs will keep reading their settings from your home directory.
- Daemons are not supposed to read your personal settings. Daemons are normally configured through files in `/etc`, not through environment variables or through files in your home directory.
- `$HOME` is supposed to have a lot of dot files. That's why `ls` doesn't show them.

Comment: I would like to ba able to easily switch to a new computer indeed. I thought putting all in `$HOME` would help me do that, but a recent pc crash has shown otherwise. Surely all my local files were easily put back (git+dropbox) but I had to fiddle a lot with the `/etc` stuff anyways to get everything right. That's why I had the idea to put everything in `/etc` and keep better track of that (again, using `git`). I geuss I'll keep it the way it is, in `$HOME`, although I lament the clutter of the home dir (XDG!!!).

Comment: Keeping config files under /home also facilitates (a) reinstalling Linux (if you have /home in a separate partition/volume, which you really should), (b) running multiple distributions and keeping your files available to all. As for `/etc` security, back up your computer regularly and you won't have issues. Dropbox counts if you don't mind the privacy/security considerations (`/etc/shadow` on the internet? The horror)

Comment: @romeovs I've been using [etckeeper](http://packages.debian.org/etckeeper) to manage `/etc` since it appeared on the scene.