# Is there a standards-specified location for user configuration files?

Tags: configuration, directory-structure, home

I'm talking about files like `~/.foo` found on a user's home dir. I'm working on a program that reads from such a file, and I'd also like to clean up my user root directory if I can.

Is there a POSIX-specified variable, such as `~/$(conf)` where config like `.emacs` can be found?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do some applications use ~/.config/appname for their config data while others use ~/.appname?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24347/why-do-some-applications-use-config-appname-for-their-config-data-while-other)

Comment: Re duplicate: I used the word POSIX in the original title to mean any standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### POSIX

Searching through the specification for the strings "user config" or "configuration files" turned up zero hits, so I would say no it doesn't specify this in any way.

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

#### FHS

Looking at the [FHS - Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) it had this bit:

> User specific configuration files for applications are stored in the user's home directory in a file that starts with the '.' character (a "dot file"). If an application needs to create more than one dot file then they should be placed in a subdirectory with a name starting with a '.' character, (a "dot directory"). In this case the configuration files should not start with the '.' character. [11](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#FTN.AEN826).

#### sysconf/getconf

Looking through the list of POSIX configuration constants present in `<limits.h>` is the only other place I can think of where something like this would be configured. Running the command `getconf <var>` will return these types of results.

For example:

```
$ getconf _POSIX_CHILD_MAX
1024
```

But looking through the list of definitions I don't see any pertaining to a user's home directory.

- [limits.h - implementation-defined constants](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html)
- [unistd.h - standard symbolic constants and types](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html)
- [sysconf - get configurable system variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sysconf.html)

Answer (score 4):

The standard that has been defined some 10+ years ago, and recently adopted, is to use `~/.config/`, `~/.cache/`, `~/.local/share/` and a few other locations to store configuration, cache and data of the user in a standard way.

This is defined by [environment](http://mdoc.su/-/env.1) variables such as `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`, `$XDG_DATA_HOME` et al.  They are still rarely pre-defined in most environments, but it might still be a good idea to test their existence, set the official defaults yourself if not already pre-set, and then use these specific variables within your own variables for configuration location; this way you can signal to any potential user, developer or source-code researcher that you're using these standard locations for configuration, cache and data (because otherwise, searching for `~/.config/` or `$HOME/.config/` may or may not work depending on the programming language and the search mechanism).

```
if [ "x$XDG_CONFIG_HOME" = "x" ] ; then
    XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config"
fi
CONFIG_FILE="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/myprog/myprog.conf"
```

For example, maybe you use Golang in your build system, and want to cache the downloaded Go packages unique to your build system in a build-specific directory, then the following shell script could be used to set it all up:

```
if [ "x$XDG_CACHE_HOME" = "x" ] ; then
    XDG_CACHE_HOME="$HOME/.cache"
fi
GO_MOD_CACHE_DIR="$XDG_CACHE_HOME/myprog/go-mod-cache"
mkdir -p "$GO_MOD_CACHE_DIR"
if [ -w "$GO_MOD_CACHE_DIR/" ] ; then
    export GOMODCACHE="$GO_MOD_CACHE_DIR"
else
    printf "WARN: GOMODCACHE directory not writeable: %s\n" "$GO_MOD_CACHE_DIR"
fi
```

References:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Base_Directory
- https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html
- http://web.archive.org/web/20101018143237/http://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Comment: It has been a long journey from remembering that $XDG_CONFIG_HOME exists to finding the name of it.  Thank you for your answer.